# Bootstrap simple example ".col-xs-3" not taking affect

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am starting out with bootstrap and am trying to create a simple column within a row, within a container.
The aim is to make the content within the column take up approximately a quarter the width of the page (or 3/12 of the grid).
Here is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrap.com/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<title>Creating Columns</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <h1>8.Creating Columns</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit. Ab libero, cupiditate veniam
    officiis itaque in porro iure fugit iusto
    reprehenderit commodi earum cum blanditiis quos
    error similique quod, facere! Hic.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this code in the browser, The Lorem Ipsum text just spans the whole
width of the browser regardless of the size of the browser.
I have also tried using the class ".col-xs-3" with no success... same result.
I would appreciate any help, as I am not to far into using bootstrap yet already
stuck.
Thank you you all very much.

Comment: It's possibly because the Bootstrap CSS CDN you are using is dead

Comment: Ah! That ought to do it... Thank you good sir.